# Como usar variables if en java para dos condiciones

Tags: java

Tengo una duda, quiero usar la variable if y que se cumpla entre un intervalo de números por ejemplo (>=0 y <=10) lo que no se y no consigo encontrar es la forma de meter esas dos condiciones en el programa les dejo aquí parte de mi código que lo usa:

```
public void Pedir_iq(){
           Scanner lectura = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce el cociente intelectual. ");
    int iq = lectura.nextInt();
    // Se debe cumplir entre dos rangos : >=79 y <= 89 
    if (iq <= 79) {System.out.println(" Iq bajo ");} 
    if (iq <= 89){System.out.println(" Iq mediano ");}
    if (iq >= 90){System.out.println(" Iq normal ");}
    if (iq >=110){System.out.println(" Iq muy alto ");}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Deberás utilizar la cláusula else if de este modo si no se cumple la primera condición el programa evaluará las siguientes condiciones que le presentes.

2.Utiliza el operador condicional AND (&&) para comprender una cantidad entre los dos condicionales entre los que tiene que estar comprendido el cociente intelectual, en las dos condiciones no puede ser igual o mayor e igual o menor, si no se cumpliría la condición en dos de las cláusulas.

```
public void Pedir_iq(){
       Scanner lectura = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Introduce el cociente intelectual. ");
int iq = lectura.nextInt();
// Se debe cumplir entre dos rangos : >=79 y <= 89 
if (iq <= 79) {System.out.println(" Iq bajo ");} 
else if (iq <= 89 && iq > 79){System.out.println(" Iq mediano ");}
else if (iq >= 90 && iq < 110){System.out.println(" Iq normal ");}
else if (iq >=110){System.out.println(" Iq muy alto ");}
```